Type modifier output differs from device to device
I was watching a video on Type Modifiers. From the basics I faced an issue, The video tutorial I was following showed me the output of Short Modifiers and Long Modifiers. But when I tried to run the same code the Long modifier output was different.
int main() {
    int a;
    a = 12;
    cout << "size of int" << sizeof(a) << endl;

    float b;
    cout << "size of float" << sizeof(b) << endl;
    
    char c;
    cout << "size of char" << sizeof(c) << endl;

    bool d;
    cout << "size of bool" << sizeof(d) << endl;

    short int si;
    long int li;
    cout << "size of shortint" << sizeof(si) << endl;
    cout << "size of longint" << sizeof(li) << endl;

    return 0;
}

I followed the code line by line and The long modifier output was supposed to be 8 but my output is 4. I also tried on a different device but got the same result as my other device. Both my devices run on x64 based windows. I am a bit confused, Is this because of the system architechture x86/x64 or something else?

The size of the data-types depends on the compilers and the hardware it target, and can differ between platforms and even between different compilers on the same platform. Also Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?. And Why sizeof built in types except char is compiler dependent in C & C++?

long has been 4 bytes on Windows since forever (40 years), even when int was only 2 bytes. For an  8 byte type we have long long, or int64_t.
